# Why Compile Apache from Source?

Tags: apache, heartbleed-bug

I'm running apache with mod_ssl on ubuntu 13.10. When I set up the server, I compiled apache with openssl from source. This made updating my server to not be vulnerable to heartbleed a big pain, especially since I'm not a professional webmaster or sysadmin, I'm a web developer.

Why does apache have to be compiled manually? Why can't I just execute

```
sudo apt-get install apache
```

This is the way I install all the rest of my software. Whats so special about apache?

Alternatively, is there an easier way that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you add it staticaly with apache module can be static and compiled with apache or dynamic. In this case you need to enable it.
the right command is :

```
  apt-get install apache2
```

**EDIT :** for ssl

For ssl try these command:

```
  a2enmod ssl
  service apache2 force-reload
```

These command will create symlink in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled pointing to /etc/apache2/mods-available

Comment: I tried this originally, but I couldn't get apache to work with mod_ssl without compiling manually.

Comment: You need to enable mod_ssl if you install apache with apt